# How to Update a column of all duplicate records in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have a table in MYSQL with this columns and data.

- **id = name**
- 1  = test
- 2  = test
- 3  = test
- 4  = ok
- 5  = ok
- 6  = ok
- 7  = yes
- 8  = no

How can I update "name" columns automaticly like this ?

- **id = name**
- 1  = test
- 2  = test1
- 3  = test2
- 4  = ok
- 5  = ok1
- 6  = ok2
- 7  = yes
- 8  = no

Comment: please have a look at this blog post- it should help you https://thesqlserverdeveloper.blogspot.com/2018/03/deleting-duplicate-records-from-table.html?view=magazine - instead of deleting, update as needed

Comment: i do not want delete duplictes. i want rename duplictes row.

Comment: yes but its the same concept - see answer below and edited comment above

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
update a set a.name=a.name+cast(rownum-1 as varchar) from #original a 
join 
(select *, row_number() OVER (partition by name ORDER BY name, id) rownum from #original)b
on a.id=b.id
where rownum<>1
```

Comment: if mysql version is not 8.0; the row number() will not work

Answer (score 0):

Create a subquery to get the sequence of numbers based on the name. Then update your table accordingly.  See demo here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/439b96/2

```
UPDATE yourTable t1
JOIN (SELECT a.id,
       case when count(*)=1 
          then a.name 
          else concat(a.name,count(*)-1) 
          end as new_name 
FROM yourTable a
JOIN yourTable b ON a.name = b.name AND a.id >= b.id
GROUP BY a.id, a.name) t2
ON t1.id=t2.id
SET t1.name=t2.new_name;
```

Answer (score 0):

I would do this with variables.

```
set @n = '';
set @rn = -1;

update t
    set name = concat(name,
                      (case when @n = name and @rn = -1
                            then if(@rn := 0, '', '')
                            when @n = name
                            then @rn := @rn + 1
                            when @n := name
                            then if(@rn := 0, '', '')
                       end)
                     )
    order by name, id;
```